# Copy ML models in HP Vertica

Tags: machine-learning, hdfs, vertica

I've started using Vertica ML (AdvancedAnalytics) on vertica 7.2.x and I need a way to copy models. (Actually this should still be an issue with 8.0.x)

- You have the `v_ml.models` table containing models meta-info. There copy should be easy
- Model data is stored in a HDFS-like structure that you can edit with `SELECT dfs_delete('some/path');` and `dfs_rename('some/path','some/otherpath');` But there is no apparent sign of a copy function.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks !